# refresh only if change

Tags: jquery, load

I load in a div like this :

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
```

I'd like to load only if there's a change in the page.
How could I do that with 'change' ?

Here's what I've tried :

```
function ()
{
    var cachedDOM = $('div#nowplaying').html();
    $.get('nowplaying.php',function(data){
        if (cachedDOM != data) {
        $('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php').fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }
    )
}, 3000);
```

The problem is that "cachedDOM != data"  is always true.

Patrick

Comment: Is it loading nowplaying.php repeatedly ?

Comment: Describe "change in the page", when should this happen?

Comment: @Xeano I think the OP means change in DOM elements.

Comment: If what is returned by 'nowplaying.php' is different, then now I want load it.  How?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need another page let you know whether it changes.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
  $.get('check_change.php', function(data) {
    if (data.changed) {
      $('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }
  });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't load when I change the 'check_change.php' content.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean something as changed in `body`. You could do something like that:

```
var cachedDOM = $('body').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    if(cachedDOM != $('body').html()) 
       $('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php',function(){cachedDOM = $('body').html();}).fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it will work. I want to check if something have changed inside 'nowplaying.php'. If yes, then load it.

Comment: So you should see xdazz's answer which is the best way to go http://stackoverflow.com/a/13892797/1414562

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loadData() {
        $('#nowplaying').load('currentsong.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }

    var result = null;

    function checkdata() {
        var scriptUrl = "currentsong.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: scriptUrl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (result != data) {
                    result = data;
                    loadData();
                };
            }
        });
    }

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
        checkdata();
    }, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See dom mutation events. Then you will be able to check something changed or not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `load`, you can use an `ajax` request and set the `ifModified`-Flag to true. This will only give you a defined response when the content of the page has changed. More setup might be required on the server side (etag) in order for this to work. 
Here a link to the docs: [jquery ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it with my example?

Comment: I dont think I answered this according to your needs, best try to implement xdazz's solution. my solution is more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you xdazz.
That's what I did :

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
function getcursong(){  
 var result = null;
 var scriptUrl = "get_current_song.php";
 $.ajax({
    url: scriptUrl,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;
    } 
 });
 return result;
}    
gcs = getcursong();
okas = $('#song').html();
if (gcs != okas){
    $('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php').fadeIn("slow");
}
}, 10000);
```